# Order of list obtained by dictionary's keys()

Tags: python

Can I expect the keys() to remain in the same order?

I plan to use them for a dropdown box and I dont want them to shift if I add or delete items from the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordered of the keys in a `dict` is not guaranteed.

[The documentation says:](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an **unordered** set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)...
>
> The `keys()` method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in **arbitrary order** (if you want it sorted, just apply the `sorted()` function to it).

Python 2.7+ and 3.1+ have the [`OrderedDict` class in `collections`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) as [described by PEP 372](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/), which does exactly what you want.  It remembers the order in which keys were added:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict()
>>> od[1] = "one"
>>> od[2] = "two"
>>> od[3] = "three"
>>> od.keys()
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

No.  According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

Answer (score 1):

No. At least in cpython (and most likely every other implementation) [you definitely can't](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items). If you want guaranteed order, check out [`odict`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/odict), which does guarantee order.

Answer (score 1):

No, not from one day to the next. keys() will be in an arbitrary order (although I think they might be consistent over the instance's lifetime, but that won't work for your menu).

Python3 has ordered dictionaries: [collections.OrderedDict documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 1):

From [python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> The **keys()** method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just apply the **sorted()** function to it).

So a way to solve this issue would be to sort the keys as soon as you "listify" them.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like an array of dictionaries or objects. Arrays are ordered. The text for the menu item would be in some field of the array or object.